# Viewing custom role properties on SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, user-permissions

I am connected to SQL Azure database via Management Studio. I have created a role and set the permissions for the role:

```
CREATE ROLE [DepartmentReadOnly] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO

GRANT SELECT ON Table1 TO DepartmentReadOnly
GRANT SELECT ON Table2 TO DepartmentReadOnly
```

Now I cannot view what permissions I have granted or not have granted to the role by right-clicking and either scripting the role or going to properties. My question is how can I view all the permissions I granted to the role (it might have been more than above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help get all the principals and permissions, if you need you can filter by role name

```
   SELECT DB_NAME() as databaseName,
   p.[name] as 'Principal_Name',
   p.[type_desc] as 'Principal_Type',
   principals2.[name] as 'Grantor',
   dbpermissions.[permission_name],
   dbpermissions.[state_desc],
   so.[Name] as 'ObjectName',
   so.[type_desc] as 'ObjectType'
   FROM [sys].[database_permissions] dbpermissions LEFT JOIN 
   [sys].[objects] so ON dbpermissions.[major_id] = so.[object_id] 
   LEFT JOIN    [sys].[database_principals] p    
   ON dbpermissions.  [grantee_principal_id] = p.[principal_id]
   LEFT JOIN [sys].[database_principals] principals2   
   ON dbpermissions.[grantor_principal_id] = principals2.[principal_id]
```